# Should you be an OOP expert if you're developing in ASP.NET?

Tags: object-oriented

Should you be an OOP expert if you're developing in ASP.NET?

Comment: Wouldnt this depend on 1) what you are actually doing in ASP.NET and 2) what 'OOP expert' means?

Comment: You should know OOP if you are coding anything beyond static pages.

Comment: Well, it certainly can't hurt to know OOP when using a platform based on an object-oriented language.

Comment: Define expert...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expert is very strong, but ASP.NET is part of the .NET platform and used with VB and C#. So I would say that you need to know OOP and how to use it. I can't see how you would be effective with ASP.NET without that knowledge.

Things like providers, factories and other design paterns are widely used throughout ASP.NET. But also the WebControls are constructed with OOP principles.

Check the following questions on stackoverflow for material:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972432/books-of-oop-programming-for-non-oop-programmers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315633/which-is-the-best-book-to-learn-and-implement-design-patterns-using-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295892/learning-oop-in-c-best-books

Comment: Do you recommend any good OO books that could contribute toward my OO learning?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295892/learning-oop-in-c-best-books http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315633/which-is-the-best-book-to-learn-and-implement-design-patterns-using-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972432/books-of-oop-programming-for-non-oop-programmers

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

How can you be a developer today and ***not*** be an OOP expert?

Comment: To be honest how many true OOP Experts have you actually met in your lifetime. If it's more than a handful then either you've worked with some really talented people or you are too liberal with your usage of the word expert.

Comment: I meet them all the time.  I guess by "expert" I mean "a guy who truly understands what he's talking about with regard to OOP".  It's not that complicated, and if you claim to be a developer and aren't an expert in OOP, then I think your claim is wrong -- just like a developer should be an expert at boolean logic or and expert at flow control in code.

Comment: Actually you can. Knowing what inheritance is and calling methods is not equal to being OOP expert.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be expert. You just need to know C#.NET/VB.NET basics which will include some OOP essential knowledge.

Moreover check some MS ASP.NET How to videos - most of them are far from real architecture, layering or OOP principles. I especially "like" those which place button in designer double click on button and write all logic and DB access to button click handler.

Comment: Quote: "I especially "like" those which place button in designer double click on button and write all logic and DB access to button click handler." <- that's the way I use to code asp.net 1.1.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: Me too but that was exactly the way how I learned what is wrong and hard to maintain and I started to learn OOP principles.

Answer (score 1):

[Expert](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expert)
1: obsolete : experienced 
2: having, involving, or displaying special skill or knowledge derived from training or experience

Yes; the language makes a lot of use with object oriented methodologies.  Knowing some OOA/D from experience/training will certainly help you in ASP.NET.

Answer (score -1):

It never hurts to know OO.  In addition asp.net sucks, go learn asp.net mvc or just quit now ;-)  said with all the humor possible.

Comment: Really? Do you seriously need to leave that type of comment? Humorous or not, it's not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @unforgiven, it was supposed to be humorous?

Comment: I don't think that type of "humor" is appropriate for this site.

Comment: Humor is always appropriate, but you're entitled to your opinion.